# Checking all values in a list have a specific constructor

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I have a function `myTest` that does a constructor check of all elements in a list.  It looks like this:

```
data MyType = Foo Int | Bar String deriving (Show, Read)

myThing :: [MyType]
myThing = [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3, Bar "fail", Foo 5]

myTest :: [MyType] -> Bool
myTest list = foldl (\ acc x -> if isOfTypeFoo x then acc else False) True list
```

I would like for `myTest` to return True if every element in the list is a `Foo`, but if there is one or more `Bar`, it returns False.  If I run `myTest myThing`, it should return `False`.

What would the function `isOfTypeFoo` look like?  (Or is there a better way to do this?)

Comment: What do you think the *type* of `isOfTypeFoo`? Also, that name is a misnomer because the *type* of `Foo x` is `MyType`. The function should really be named `isFoo` or similar.

Comment: You can write the desired function quite nicely with `LambdaCase`: `\case { Foo _ -> True; _ -> False }`, you can of course use `foldl`, or you can write `all $ \case { Foo _ -> True; _ -> False }`.

Comment: @user2407038, `foldl` is inappropriate here. `foldr` would make good sense, or, as you mentioned, `all`.

Comment: @dfeuer Why is foldr better than foldl?

Comment: @MarkKaravan, `foldr` allows short-circuiting; `foldl` does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can start with writing the predicate for a single `MyType`:

```
isFoo :: MyType -> Bool
isFoo (Foo _) = True
isFoo _       = False
```

then you can extend it to lists using [`all`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:all):

```
isAllFoo :: [MyType] -> Bool
isAllFoo = all isFoo
```

Comment: @MarkKaravan, there is no type check here. Haskell types are erased in compilation. You should stop thinking of what happens at runtime as checking for a type and start thinking of it as matching on constructors.

Comment: @MarkKaravan: In C terms, you essentially have `union MyType { int tag; struct { int tag; int *value; } as_foo; struct { int tag; string *value; } as_bar; };` and `case x of { Foo y -> … }` is simply saying `if (x.tag == FOO_TAG) { y = x.as_foo.value; … }`.